# Angularjs call a controller method every time custom directive select changes

Tags: angularjs, select, controller, action, directive

I have written a custom directive for select component. The problem I face is `simpleComboSelectionChanged()` prints the previous selected value and not the current value. Please let me know what is the problem.

directive & Controller:

```js
.directive('simpleSelect', [function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      require: '^ngModel',
      scope:{
       id: '@',
       ngModel: '=',
       items: '=',
       ngChange: '&'
      },
      // linking method
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.updateModel = function()
       {
     scope.ngChange();
       };
     }, 
      template:'<select class="form-control" id="id" ng-model="ngModel" ng-selected="ngModel" ng-options="Type.type as Type.name | translate for Type in items"'+
      'ng-change="updateModel()"></select>'
    };
  }])



.controller('ComboTemplateCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.ComboItems = [{type:1, name:"Combo.Item1", isSet:false},
                   {type:2, name:"Combo.Item2", isSet:false},
                   {type:3, name:"Combo.Item3", isSet:false},
                   {type:4, name:"Combo.Item4", isSet:false},
                   {type:5, name:"Combo.Item5", isSet:false}
                    ];
    $scope.simpleSelectValue = $scope.ComboItems[0].type;
      
    $scope.simpleComboSelectionChanged = function(){
     console.log("Selected Item is :", $scope.simpleSelectValue);
     
    };
  }])
```

```html
<simple-select id="simpleSelectTest" 
               ng-model="simpleSelectValue" items="ComboItems" 
               ng-change="simpleComboSelectionChanged()"></simple-select>
```

Comment: Any update? Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because you are binding to `ngModel` as opposed to `require: "ngModel"` and using the `ngModelController` API to modify it. (You are, in fact, use `require`, but you aren't actually using. Neither are you using `transclude` which is not needed here).

What happens is the inner `ngModel`-bound variable - `scope.ngModel` - is changed to the currently selected item, then the inner `ng-change` is fired, which invokes the outer `ng-change`, which tries to read the outer variable bound to `ng-model` attribute - `$scope.simpleSelectValue`. But `$scope.simpleSelectValue` hasn't yet changed - this will happen on a `$watch` that will occur later.

The main point is - this is not how `ngModel` is meant to be used.

`ngModel` is a directive that custom input control authors (like yourself) can use to integrate with other `ngModel`-compatible directives (such as `form`, `ng-required`, `ng-change` and other custom directives) that can validate, transform, or just listen to changes of input values.

Since you are building a custom input control essentially (even if you are using a built-in control under the covers), you need to support your own `ngModel`.

Here's a conceptual overview of how this can be done:

```
.directive('simpleSelect',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        id: '@',
        items: '=',
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$render = function(){
          scope.selectedValue = ngModel.$viewValue;
        };

        scope.onChange = function(){
          ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.selectedValue);
        };
      },
      template: '<select class="form-control" id="id" ng-model="selectedValue"' +
                        'ng-options="Type.type as Type.name for Type in items"' +
                        'ng-change="onChange()">' +
                '</select>'
    };
  });
```

`ngModel.$render` is fired when rendering is required (for example, when model value changes) - all that you need to do here is to set the value bound to inner `ng-model` - no need even to do direct DOM manipulation.

`ngModel.$setViewValue` is called when the input directive receives input from the user. Again, since you are using an existing input directive `<select>`, then you could just rely on its `ng-change`.

You will also notice that there is no longer a need to have your own `ng-change`. That is the value of `ngModel` support - a consumer of your directive can just treat your input control like any other, include support for `ng-change`.

Read more about [custom input controls](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will read in detail and try. Pls do share the links from which I can learn more on custom directives concept.

Comment: @Nini, SO is not a place to ask for a link to a tutorial, but I gave you a link at the bottom of my answer about custom input controls.